# Django Attribute Error - form object has no attribute is_valid error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I keep getting an error saying that my BundleForm has no attribute is_valid.  I double and triple checked and my BundleForm is associated with a model, specifically my Bundle model.  I can't figure out why else I would be getting this error.  Any comments/input greatly welcomed!

models.py

```
class Bundle(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class BundleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        help_text='Enter mission name. Change to hidden unless mouse over. ',
        initial='bundle_name',
        required=True,
        max_length=50,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Bundle             
        fields = ('name',)
```

views.py

```
def new_bundle(request):
form1 = BundleForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = BundleForm(request.POST)
    if form1.is_vaild():
        bundle = form1.save(commit=True)
        return render(request, 'build_a_bundle/new_bundle.html', {'bundle':bundle})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Form 1 Error')    
return render(request, 'build_a_bundle/new_bundle.html', {'form1':form1})
```

Comment: I literally just had this same typo =|.

Answer (score 4):

There's a syntax error, change `if form1.is_vaild():` to : `if form1.is_valid():`.

Comment: Ahh, you are my hero =]

Comment: @iHeartKayk No problem, `has no attribute ...` errors are often are related to syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error. I've made the same mistake too.

.is_vaild()

```js
.is_valid()
```